# Menu Item To New Activity

Tags: java, android, menu, android-activity

I'm trying to send the user to a new activity using a menu button, and back again. To put it into context, I have a basic calculator that runs when the app is opened (works perfect right now), then I want the user to hit the menu button on his/her phone, (two buttons should pop up Home and Tip Calculator) when the user hits tip calculator it should then load the new activity TipCalculator. Then if the menu button is pressed again, the same two options should appear and the Home button should bring them back to the basic calculator.

This is my Code for the Calculator.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calculator, menu);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE,HOME_MENU_ID,Menu.NONE,"Home");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,SECOND_MENU_ID,Menu.NONE,"Tip Calculator");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(item.getItemId()){

        case HOME_MENU_ID:
            Intent main = new Intent(this,Calculator.class);
            startActivity(main);
            finish();
        return true;

        case SECOND_MENU_ID:
            Intent second = new Intent(this,TipCalculator.class);
            startActivity(second);
            finish();
        return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This is the code for the TipCalculator.java

```
    public class TipCalculator extends Calculator{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tipcalculator);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tipcalculator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent main = new Intent(this,Calculator.class);
    startActivity(main);
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

The menu comes up fine, and the home button will refresh the home page, but the tip calculator button gives me a force close error and crashes on me.

Comment: You are calling finish() on the current activity after starting the new intent - is this not destroying the activity that you wish to return to?

Comment: Have you added the TipCalculator activity to your manifest?

Comment: force close error = Logcat required